# Wizard/NSUserDefaults with storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

I'm trying to make an app which has a setup that has a table view and each table cell redirects to another view with a button if you would like to confirm that the information is correct and if it's correct save the data so the wizard won't appear again.

I'm having a hard time to achieve this I tried the following things:

- State preservation and restoration with [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_6_iPhone_State_Preservation_and_Restoration_Tutorial) tutorial, but the problem is whenever the user stops the app via the iOS Multitasking bar the App won't restore..
- Saving a string to the NSUserDefaults storage and read it again when the app launches, the biggest problem with this is that I'm using a story board which takes care of the launching part so I can't code to launch another view.

So I'm stuck for now, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

use the table view delegate method:

(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

You will know which cell is selected with indexPath. From there save your work with NSUserDefaults

Comment: But, after tapping on a table cell the user shall be redirected to a page where he/se can confirm that the information is correct, so I guess this is not the right solution.